# LibreCalc function for extracting non-null values to a list

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Firstly sorry for bad english/phrasing, I feel like the question doesn't really describe my problem, but oh well, it will be described below. All/any recommendations for clearer phrasing is appreciated.

On to the problem. I think an example will greatly help with the question.
Lets say I have a spreadsheet

> ```
> no.  val.1  val.2
> 1    /      a
> 2    X      b
> 3    /      c
> 4    Y      d
> 5    /      e
> ```

I want to extract val.2 values where val.1 is different from '/', but I want them to be one after another. The end result should be another column:

> ```
> no.  val.1  val.2  res
> 1    /      a      b
> 2    X      b      d
> 3    /      c      
> 4    Y      d
> 5    /      e
> ```

Only rows 2 and 4 are extracted, but put in 1 and 2 respectively.

I already know how to use IF, but it doesn't put values one after the other.

Is there a way to achieve what I have in mind, and if yes how?

Comment: The example and question are clear.  Hopefully, it is a close enough representation of your actual problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select column B and go to *Data -> Auto Filter*.  Then in the filter drop-down, uncheck `/`.

[image: filter showing rows 3 and 5]

If you want to move the results to rows 1 and 2, then copy and paste the results.